# Can a class and its parent contain member variable of the same name?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I made the following examples to demostrate. If I use `name` in both `Song` and `KarokeSong` class, I get an error.

```
class Song
  def initialize(name, artist, duration)
    @name = name
    @artist = artist
    @duration = duration
  end

  def to_s
    "Song: #{@name}--#{@artist} (#{@duration})"
  end
end

class KarokeSong < Song
  def initalize(name, kname, artist, duration, lyrics)
    super(name, artist, duration)
    @name = kname
    @lyrics = lyrics
  end

  def to_s
    "KS: #{@name}--#{@artist} (#{@duration}) [#{@lyrics}] **#{@name}**"
  end
end

songA = Song.new("Bicyclops", "Fleck", 260)
puts songA.to_s

songB = KarokeSong.new("John", "Casey", "The Band", 400, "And now, the...")
puts songB.to_s
```

Here is the error that I've received when trying to run the file.

```
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby$ ruby inheritance.rb
Song: Bicyclops--Fleck (260)
inheritance.rb:28:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments(5 for 3) (ArgumentError)
    from inheritance.rb:28:in `new'
    from inheritance.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I'm guessing using the name `name` twice is not allowed if there's an inheritance relationship. I'm not sure if it has to do with the fact that Ruby doesn't support multiple-inheritance or V-pointers. Thanks in advance for your suggestions of what's happening.

Comment: `class KaraokeSong < Song` should get you in the right direction.

Comment: OMG...totally forgot about `< Song`.

Comment: Even after correcting that detail, I'm still getting a similar error. Check the updates to the question.

Comment: @Casper: I don't know if that's intended to be a joke, but I spelled it as `KarokeSong` in both the class definition and when I instantiated an object of the same class. So I don't think it should've mattered.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, but you mispelled `initialize` as `initalize` in `KarokeSong` :-/

Comment: @Casper: Well, you are right about the part where I need the sleep or coffee. Now I realize @name refers to the `@name` in the parent class, not in itself (KarokeSong). The result is more of a logic error rather than a runtime error.

Comment: Yep. That's right. The instance variable will be shared across the inheritance. So looks like you're on the right track now :)

Comment: @Casper: So there's no way for both parent and child class to have its own `@name` member variable in Ruby?

Comment: No, as far as I know instance variables are shared across the inheritance tree. So you need to figure out some other way  or naming convention for those.

Comment: @Casper: Hashes are probably better suited for that, from what I've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that KaraokeSong isn't inheriting from Song.

Change the KaraokeSong class definition to `class KaraokeSong < Song`

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to the question in the title: instance variables are bound to the object, not to the class. `@name` will always refer to the same variable within a given object, no matter which class the method that accessed it belongs to.

```
super name     # assigns name to @name
@name = kname  # overwrites name with kname
```